# I want my website to load with direct access URL on netlify

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, redirect, routes, netlify

So I've made a simple project with vanilla JS and also made URL routing possible, However I've also learnt that to make direct URL access possible you should modify the .htaccess file to make index.html the main file for the server, however I'm planning to deploy it to netlify and I've learnt that netlify doesn't support .htaccess

So can someone please guide me to achieve direct URL access on netlify?

PS - I have seperate .html files for seperate routes within a directory named 'pages' and NO FRAMEWORKS HAVE BEEN USED TO DEVELOP THIS PROJECT

Answer (score 0):

make sure make your main html file must have naming

> index.html